# How to serialize a string with double byte characters?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I want to serialize a string (Korean string) containing double byte characters. Do I need to do something special?

I am able to serialize `char *` strings by escaping special characters like \n,\b,\f,\t etc.

I am using C++ on Windows without any libraries.

Comment: You have a much greater chance to get your question answered if you specify what you mean by serialize. Whether you need to do something special or not completely depends on what you mean by *serialize* so until you explain that in more detail you'll most likely not get any reasonable responses to your question.

Comment: okay I want to pass that string to another com object.Basically Javascript will be calling my API to get the serialized data.

Comment: COM uses the UTF-16 encoded BSTR data type for all of its strings.  Scripting environments, like Javascript, then wrap everything inside of VARIANT values.  So you would need to encode/decode your double-byte strings to/from UTF-16 when passing them around COM.

Answer (score 0):

You want to transform a Unicode string in bytes. An Unicode string can be represented in many ways in memory so you need to encode it. I

I recommend to use `UTF-8` encoding for this because it the most used encoding it that is also independent of machine endianess.